# Problem with beamer and the vertical alignment in the header and footer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, vertical-alignment

I use Latex with beamer and Warsaw to create a presentation:

```
\documentclass[9pt, compress, aspectratio=169]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}                          
\usecolortheme{beaver}                     
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

Unfortunately, the text in the footer and header is not vertically averaged out. The text is displayed at the top of the footer and header. Half a year ago this behavior did not exist. The text was displayed vertically centered. Is this an error in a new version of beamer?